# Windows Installer - Ejecutar programa después de instalar

Tags: .net, windows-forms, windows-installer

Tengo un proyecto en .net, esta funcionando correctamente pero quiero que cuando termine la instalación se ejecute el programa automáticamente, busque la documentación pero no había nada al respecto, ¿alguna idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estas usando Visual Studio Installer puedes hacer lo siguiente

Paso 1: agregue una nueva clase de instalador al proyecto de aplicación que desea ejecutar después de la instalación, llámelo como desee.

Paso 2: agregue el siguiente código a la clase de instalador que acaba de agregar y rellene MyApplication.exe con el nombre del suyo.

```
Public Overrides Sub Commit(ByVal savedState As System.Collections.IDictionary)

    MyBase.Commit(savedState)
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Me.Context.Parameters("AssemblyPath")) + "\MyApplication.exe")

End Sub
```